# Zend 1.12 and IMAP: Create folders fails

Tags: php, zend-framework, imap

I'm connecting to an IMAP-mailbox and trying to create the folder INBOX/test using PHP and Zend 1.12:

```
$this->Mail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap(array(
                    'host'      => $this->sHost,
                    'port'      => $this->nPort,
                    'user'      => $this->sUser,
                    'password'  => $this->sPass,
                    'ssl'       => $this->sSsl,
                    'folder'    => 'INBOX')); // Works, I can get all messages in INBOX for example

$allFolders = $this->Mail->getFolders('INBOX'); // Throws  'Zend_Mail_Storage_Exception' with message 'folder not found'

$this->Mail->createFolder('test', 'INBOX'); // Throws 'Zend_Mail_Storage_Exception' with message 'cannot create folder'

$Folder = $this->Mail->getFolders()->INBOX; // Works, so INBOX is there
```

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
$allFolders = $this->Mail->getFolders('INBOX.');
$this->Mail->createFolder('INBOX.test');
```

Mind the dot behind INBOX, this makes it work.